# Working with Excel Files in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, excel, xls

I'm trying to save some data to an Excel file from Adobe AIR. I'm using the as3xls library hosted on Google Code, but it doesn't seem to SAVE formulas. For example, if I set the value of a cell to `=SUM(B1:B38)`, it evaluates it as a string when I open the saved document. I was curious if any export here has any sort of knowledge on how to build in formulas into an Excel document. I'm not too saavy on the XLS or XLSX data format.

I am familiar with many other programming languages, so if someone knows of a really great library for doing this sort of thing, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I have been not try it, but Try it:
[as3xls.swc](http://code.google.com/p/as3xls/)

Comment: I said in my question that I'm using this library.